# Creating Azure AD B2C Social Account using graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I have added google and facebook as Identity Provider for my Azure AD B2C tenant. Now I want to add social users for both google and facebook using azure ad graph api.

In api documentation it is mentioned that "userIdentities" is required attribute which is having to sub attributes "issuer" and "issuerUserId" . for "issuer" it is quite clear what should be the value , but am not able to find how to get  "issuerUserId" for identityProvider.

It is described as "The unique user identifier used by the social identity provider" , earlier i thought it is unique for identity provider but when tried it is not . Different value needs to passed for different user of same identity provider .

I went through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claimstransformations , so i think it is related to user attributes but still not sure how generate value to pass into the api call?

How to resolve?

Comment: you can only create users for local account but you can invite users that have google and or facebook account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are referring to the documentation for [user migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-social-migration) here. 
The documentation mentions

> Depending on the identity provider, the Issuer User ID is a unique
>   value for a given user per application or development account.
>   Configure the Azure AD B2C policy with the same application ID that
>   was previously assigned by the social provider or another application
>   within the same development account.

The assumption here is when you are migrating user from old systems you already have such `unique identifier` from the social accounts such as Google and Facebook. It can be used in base 64 encoded form.

**It'll also help to understand what is your scenario?**

Comment: Thanks abhishek for reposne .  Yes it was "unique identifier" used that social account for Google it was its object id. You were correct in assumption that it is considered as user migration . My scenario was creating B2C social account of any person by just having there email and identity provider but seems its not possible as we cannot get a users "unique identifier" unless we own that account